# Not able to use variable defined in karate-config.js in my feature file

Tags: karate

I want to set a Global variable for Base Test Data location which can be used in all of my feature files.
In karate-config.js i have made below changes -

var config = {
    env: env,
    INPUT_JSON_PATH: 'com/company/project/module/TestData'
  }

And in my feature file I am trying to use it as -

Given path '/myService'
    And request read('classname:INPUT_JSON_PATH/Exception_Handling/Mandatory_Fields_missing.json')
    When method POST
    Then status 400

But somehow its not getting resolved and I am getting error - 
could not find or read file: classname:INPUT_JSON_PATH/Exception_Handling/Mandatory_Fields_missing.json

Any idea, what am i missing here?

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep in mind that `read()` and other parts of the right-hand-side are treated as [ordinary JavaScript](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions). Maybe you were intending to do this:

```
And request read('classpath:' + INPUT_JSON_PATH + '/Exception_Handling/Mandatory_Fields_missing.json')
```